# How to handle dpkg was interrupted error?

Tags: ubuntu

This question is referring to the ubuntu-run PC, where I was installing a package, which got interrupted due to the reason that the repository location is not accessible anymore. 
As a result, I had to abort the install operation. 
But later on, whenever I tried to install any other package, I was getting the dpkg was interrupted error. I tried out all the suggestions mentioned, on the terminal. But I had no success. Can people please help find me a way to get my system out of this state (ofcourse, without having to re-install the OS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is repair DPKG with following command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I suspect the OP already tried this, as that's what the error message tells you to do; but with no actual diagnostics, there isn't much we can do. Not a programming question anyway.